# Text appearing above textarea with jQuery highlightTextarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I've been trying to use [jQuery highlightTextarea] (https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea) but I came accross the following issue below where the text appears above the textarea. What could cause this?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/highlighttextarea.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/highlighttextarea.css"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at massa non erat convallis vulputate molestie nec dui. Donec auctor blandit nibh quis luctus. Donec tincidunt auctor consequat.</textarea>
</div>

<script>
  $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate']
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

While I'm expecting this from the documentation:

[image]

Comment: are you finding issues with exact match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the css correctly,

Change:

```
<script src="/jquery/highlighttextarea.css"></script>
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.highlighttextarea.css"/>
```